# How to use the PIXLR editor on Google Drive images

Tags: google-chrome, images, google-drive

I am trying to use an editor in Google Drive images — the PIXLR editor —, but is giving me errors as shown in the screenshot below.

I had an image which when I wanted to open

[image: image to open]

[image: open with screenshot]

[image: pixlr editor 404 error]

In last screenshot you can see I get a 404 not found error and this is not only for this image. Any screenshot which I want to open with this app in Google gives me this 404 not found error.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why don't you sync your files with your hard drive, and use an offline editor?

Comment: manytimes I am in a situation where I am posting screenshots as you can read in comments section in this thread 1)https://serverfault.com/questions/994722/nslookup-failures-unknown-cant-find-www-vmware-com-query-refused 2)https://superuser.com/questions/1507968/virtual-machine-not-having-internet-connectivity

3)https://serverfault.com/questions/994622/internet-connectivity-failure-in-virtual-machines-on-workstation
then before posting images on internet I save them in Google drive and editing them online makes my work faster , I have several thousands of images which I have saved

Comment: and just for ease of use I have to upload them on google drive or for the sake of posting on various forums I have to put them in google drive and when I am doing so I have 100s of tabs and 2 virtual machines open in my laptop which makes my laptop extremely slow like mentioned in this thread https://superuser.com/questions/1507247/what-could-be-cause-of-my-slow-running-laptop-on-windows-10  so it is better at times for me to use an online service. I do edit a lot of screenshots as and when I get time on my local computer it is just that I need these things a lot so I tried an online app which

Comment: google showed in when I logged in to my google drive.

Comment: My point is that with [Backup and Sync](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/) or [InSync](https://www.insynchq.com/), the files you store on your computer will automatically be stored in Google Drive, even as you edit them, so you can easily share the files on your computer that way. I was enquiring why you don't use one of those tools.

Comment: 1) I was not aware of this kind of thing backup and sync and 2) the screenshots I post may not be necessarily from same computer I may be logged in to machines at times different than my computer like home, work or friends computers etc. I have a shared laptop which may be used by family members friends I do not want them to see all photos in my google backup or some folder etc etc.

Comment: As long as it is your computer, you can install the sync client on all your computers, and your files will be the same across all your computers...